# WSO2 EI 6.4.0 publish in Jaeger

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, jaeger

I am trying to publish the flow traces of the wso2 EI 6.4.0 messages in Jaeger.
My question is:
Does Jaeger support WSO2 EI version 6.4.0? Are there other alternatives for this version of WSO2?

Thank you very much and greetings

Answer (score 1):

Jaeger tracing support is available from EI-6.6.0 version onwards.

However you can use the Analytics profile of WSO2 EI-6.4.0 to monitor statistics related to the message mediation that is carried out by the ESB profile of WSO2 EI.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Working+with+Analytics